# CentOS7 SFTP - Not Detecting Private Key

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 server with OpenSSH installed which it's primary purpose is to be an SFTP server. I have several clients who connect to this server using either Private/Public Key authentication or Passwords and they all connect fine.

I have one particular client who is connecting to our server using GlobalScape EFT 5.1 with a combination of Password and Private/Public Key.

The public key they provided us with starts with the comment below and is over multiple lines.

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

I converted the public key using SSH-KEYGEN -i -f and placed it inside the authorized_keys file. It is now on one line and starts with ssh-rsa.

On looking at the logs (which I have pasted below) it does not seem to be recognising that they are using a key.

```
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: oom_adjust_restore
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 8 sock 9
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: Connection from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 4387
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version GSSFTP1.0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: no match: GSSFTP1.0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: Network child is on pid 11108
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: preauth child monitor started
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: privsep user:group 74:74
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Wrote 840 bytes for a total of 861
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 3des-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 3des-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib,none
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib,none
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 78
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 79
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 78
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 79
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 78
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 79
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 78
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 79
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 208/384
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: bits set: 502/1024
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: bits set: 539/1024
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_key_sign entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 5
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 6
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 5
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_sign
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x7fe361d8dbf0(271)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: kex_derive_keys
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Wrote 720 bytes for a total of 1581
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: monitor_read: 5 used once, disabling now
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: KEX done
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1629
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: userauth-request for user SFTPUserName service ssh-connection method none
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 8
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 7
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: Trying to reverse map address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 901
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: checking match for 'User SFTPUserName' user SFTPUserName host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX addr XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: user ScotPower matched 'User SFTPUserName' at line 147
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: match found
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: reprocess config:148 setting ForceCommand internal-sftp
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: reprocess config:149 setting AllowTCPForwarding no
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for SFTPUserName
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_start_pam entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 50
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 3
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_inform_authrole entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Wrote 80 bytes for a total of 1709
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: monitor_read: 7 used once, disabling now
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 50
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "SFTPUserName"
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: monitor_read: 50 used once, disabling now
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 3
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: monitor_read: 3 used once, disabling now
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_authrole: role=
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: userauth-request for user SFTPUserName service ssh-connection method password
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_auth_password entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 11
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 12
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 11
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_passwd_conv called with 1 messages
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for SFTPUserName
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 51
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_auth_password: user authenticated
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_do_pam_account entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 51
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 52
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: PAM: do_pam_account pam_acct_mgmt = 0 (Success)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 52
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: Accepted password for SFTPUserName from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 4387 ssh2
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_do_pam_account returning 1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: SFTPUserName has been authenticated by privileged process
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 1741
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 25
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending new keys: 0x7fe361d8d950 0x7fe361d8ebf0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x7fe361d8d950
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x7fe361d8ebf0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: New keys have been sent
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending compression state
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 25
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 80
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 81
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11108]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x7fe361da19f0(120)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for second key
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x7fe361da19f0(120)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting compression state
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting Network I/O buffers
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 80
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 81
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync end
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 504/504 (e=0/0)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: PAM: opening session
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 504/504 (e=0/0)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: User child is on pid 11109
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 504/504
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 100000 max 8192
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: input_session_request
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: session_open: channel 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1789
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request subsystem reply 1
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req subsystem
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: subsystem request for sftp
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: subsystem: exec() internal-sftp -l DEBUG3 -f AUTH
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: Forced command (config) 'internal-sftp'
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_audit_run_command entering command internal-sftp
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 62
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 63
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 62
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_audit_command entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 63
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: Wrote 72 bytes for a total of 1861
Sep 30 15:49:37 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: Wrote 136 bytes for a total of 1997
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: Connection closed by XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:\r\n  #0 server-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 9/8 cc -1)\r\n
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 9 w 8 e 11
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: session_close: session 0 pid 11110
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_audit_end_command entering command internal-sftp
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 64
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug1: do_cleanup
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 80
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 81
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 64
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_audit_end_command entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_session_close: session 0 pid 0
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_session_close: command 0
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 80
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 81
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: Transferred: sent 1864, received 2744 bytes
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: Closing connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 4387
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_audit_event entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 61
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 61
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11109]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 65
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_audit_event entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 65
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug3: mm_answer_term: tearing down sessions
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: closing session
Sep 30 15:49:47 server14 sshd[11107]: debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

I must add that we recently upgraded the server from CentOS6 to 7 and the connection used to work on CentOS6. As far as I can tell the configuration is identical.

Below is the current sshd_config file that we are using.

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
# activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel DEBUG3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
ClientAliveCountMax 10
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
PermitTunnel yes
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp -l VERBOSE -f AUTH

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

# tail /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Match User SFTPUserName
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTCPForwarding no
```

Answer (score 0):

In server log, there is not used `pubkey` authentication method, so I would rather blame client that he is not sending the key.

Since the client is using some non-standard software (that I have never heard of before) it is possible there appeared some incompatibility during the time since centos6 release on one or the other side.

[Updating](https://www.globalscape.com/support/eft-enterprise) the client to current version should help: EFT 5.1 is 8 years old!

Comment: At present the client is saying that it used to work and the only change has been our server. I don't think updating from EFT 5.1 is an option :(

Comment: yes, but it is not excuse to use such outdated software. I don't believe it is even supported after so many years